# Replace a blank before a table page break Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, bi-publisher

I uncheck "Allow row to break across pages" for a table's properties So, the table is shown on a new page to ensure that all the content is on one page, this works fine. But Word generates a blank space before the page break, I need to replace it with some text for a legal reason. I can't use a watermark or shapes because un Oracle BI Publisher only prints it on PDF and I need to export it to a docx.

The data is dynamic, so sometimes the text before the table and the text inside the table may change.

Current Version https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPyDx.jpg
I need some like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRzFi.jpg

MS Office support told me that it can't be done with Word...
Maybe with VBA code?

Update

Thanks Cindy for your help.

I have a table into another table many paragraphs, checkbox etc and they are fitting on a new page. It's working.

I understand there isn't a page break.
It's Paragraph mark.
But what I need to do is insert a kind of mark, a text like XXXX,-----------,  Instead of leaving "free space",

It's a requirement not change the font size or another text format. 
For a legal requirement, some paragraph must fit on a new page and "blank spaces" replaced by a kind of mark.
I can't hard code it because in several cases not all the paragraphs or section in a page will be shown and I don't know by default when a new page is needed.
 I am available to use macros or anything.

Comment: I wanted to insert your pictures, but they're not in a supported format. Please try to upload *.png - with your rep you won't be able to, but we can.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you need, but: A Word table *must* have an empty paragraph mark following the table. Some of the table structures are stored in that paragraph mark. (If you're not displaying non-printing characters you won't see the paragraph mark, but it's not "a blank space".) If it's too much space, select the paragraph and apply a smaller font size. You can type in the font size box in the Ribbon; the smallest number it accepts is 1. Or you can format it as "Hidden" using the font formatting dialog box.

Comment: For one, "Allow row to break across pages" has no effect on the table as a whole. If you want to ensure that it is on one page format the paragraphs within the table as "Keep with next". Provided that the table actually fits on one page that should dispense with your need for a PageBreak.

Comment: Assuming that you are talking about a vertical space, the PageBreak doesn't generate such a space. Instead, the "logic" is that one should have the PageBreak after the text that preceeds it which usually means that the PageBreak is in a new paragraph, and that is the one that generates a space. Format it as Cindy has suggested, or add the PageBreak at the end of the preceeding paragraph, not in a paragraph of its own.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is insert a page-size table into a textbox in the page header and format the body text with a white background. The table will thus be hidden behind any text on the page, but not otherwise (provided you don't pad unused space with empty paragraphs, etc.).